# Why does my PC awake from sleep when random, unrelated objects get static shocked?

Tags: desktop-computer, static-discharge

Okay this is really bizarre. Just recently I noticed that when I touch objects sitting on my desk and receive a static shock, my computer (desktop tower on the floor under desk) awakens from sleep. One example is my wireless Xbox 360 controller. It's just a plastic controller sitting on my wooden desk, all by itself. When I touched it earlier and received a small shock, my PC awoke from sleep. This also happened when I touched my TV remote which was sitting on my computer desk. When I went to pick it up and received a small shock, computer woke up.

Comment: You might want to check that nothing is improperly grounding out, especially if your tower is directly on the floor. Chances are your computers case or power supply is inadvertently receiving the discharge as well.

Comment: How in the world can you get a shock from touching a plastic cased device? A TV remote is not even connected to anything, getting a shock from it is basically impossible. What kind of place do you live in? Maybe you should turn off the giant *van de Graaff* generator next to your chair?

Comment: @no comprende You can get static shock from anything. The polyester clothes you pull out of a dryer can produce a laser show and they're nothing but "plastic".

Comment: I guess you shouldn't put the remote in the dryer.